# KeyDown before TextChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I wonder if it's possible to make `KeyDown` event trigger before `TextChanged`?

I have added these two events for a simple `TextBox` and now I want to check if `Delete` key was pressed. If yes, `<do nothing>`, if no `<so something>`. I have created a `boolean` field, that "remembers" if I pressed `Delete`, but the problem is `KeyDown` triggers after `TextChanged`, so it doesn't work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To cancel Keydown event you can add a PreviewKeyDown:

```
private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Key == Key.Delete)
     e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

what about `PreviewKeyDown` event?

Edit:

`PreviewKeyDown` event is a tunneling routed event, it travels down the containment hierarchy.
`KeyDown` event is a bubbling routed event, it travels up the containment hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks, it worked:) I didn't know what's the difference between Preview and normal KeyDown:)